# Gmap.js How to HIDE (not delete) marker. Cannot find this anywhere

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Using [*gmap.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/)
I'm trying to create a filter to show certain google map markers that have certain tags.

I setup a little demo jsFiddle here -->  http://jsfiddle.net/2PP5a/1/

gmap.js does not seem to show how to "HIDE" markers. They show how to "DELETE" but not hide. And once you hide the marker, how do you bring it back?

I have no idea where to begin. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ex2").slider({});

  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: 29.5714305,
    lng: -98.6744044,
    zoom:10,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style : 'BIG',
        position: 'TOP'
    },
    panControl : false,
    streetViewControl : false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
  }); 

var orangex = '|FFa500|000000';
var bluex = '|0000FF|FFFFFF';
var redx = '|FF0000|FFFFFF';
var xcol;



    $('.markers li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        latlng = $this.data('latlng').split(','),
        color = $this.data('color'),
        place = $this.data('place'),
        myval = $this.data('val'),
        titlex = $this.data('title');

     // if(isNaN(latx)) { alert('not a number'); } else { alert('yep its a number');}
        if(color=='orange') {xcol = orangex;} 
        else if (color=='blue') {xcol = bluex;}
      else if (color=='red') {xcol = redx;}
      else {xcol=orangex;}

        map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng[0],
            lng: latlng[1],
            tag:[color, myval, place],
            icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + myval + xcol,
            title: titlex
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the demo doesn't contain code that deletes any marker

Comment: @Dr.Molle I'm not trying to delete markers - only hide them. But here's the documentation -> http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-removeMarkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `removeMarkers`-method clears the `markers`-collection, the markers will not be accessible anymore when you use this method.

Iterate over the markers instead and set the `map`-property to `null` or a maps-instance :

```
//hide all markers:
$.each(map.markers,function(){this.setMap(null)});
//show all markers:
$.each(map.markers,function(){this.setMap(map.map)});
```